# How to return a "double" value to two decimal places in C++

Tags: c++, double, decimal

```
double calc_percent_of_daily_sugar(int sugar) {
  double result;
  result = sugar/avg_sugar_intake;
  return result*100;
}
```

I'm trying to get this function to return the result to only 2 decimal places however when I try to use `cout << setprecision(2) << result;` then there are still more than 2 places in the number
Apologies if this is a nooby or stupid question.

Comment: Do you want the function to return `int` or print `double` as an integer?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. Then tell us what kind of output you would want instead of the ones you get.

Comment: You can't. Doubles don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and the two are incommensurable. If you want decimal places you have to use a decimal radix. Typically this is done when producing text output, not while calculating.

Comment: it's a hacky thing but you can multiply by 100.0, take the integer part and then divide by 100.0 again.

Answer (score 1):

> *How to **print** a “double” value to two decimal places **in base 10** in C++

Use `std::fixed` to print it in decimal.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << 123.4567 << std::endl;
// 123.46
```

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: What do I have to include to use setprecision and std:::fixed?

Comment: Click on the link included the question. On top in the redirected page, you wil see text "Defined in header <someheader>". This text specifies what you have to include.

Comment: it says ios but I believe I included iomanip to get it working